# Starting the very first sentence with « mais » with no connection whatsoever with the preceding context

Tags: conjonctions

> **Mais** qu'est-ce qui lui a pris de choisir une tenue aussi quelconque ?
>
> vs : Qu'est-ce qui lui a pris de choisir une tenue aussi quelconque ?

What does it add to the meaning of the sentence to start a conversation with « mais » like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cet emploi de la conjonction **mais** correspond à celui décrit dans le [TLFI](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mais) **II**. **B**. a)

> [L'énoncé introd. par mais est mis en relation avec la situation extra-linguistique et non avec un énoncé qui le précède]

Le locuteur exprime ici son étonnement et sa désapprobation (situation extra linguistique) vis à vis de la situation actuelle. La phrase de l'exemple est ponctuée par un point d'interrogation et donc peut aussi être perçue linguistiquement comme une demande d'explication à la personne à laquelle  on s'adresse.
Mais la phrase pourrait se terminer simplement par un point d'exclamation et ne refléter donc que l'étonnement et la désapprobation, sans demande d'explication.

Dire uniquement :

> Qu'est-ce qui lui a pris de choisir une tenue aussi quelconque ?

diminue le poids du jugement (désapprobation et étonnement) en réduisant l'énoncé à une simple question. Je dis « diminue » parce que ces valeurs restent présentes dans l'emploi du mot « quelconque » et de « prendre ».

Comment: L'expression « qu'est-ce qui lui a pris » elle-même exprime déjà son étonnement et sa désapprobation, alors « mais » ajoute aux sentiments, c’est bien ça ? :) Merci.

Comment: Oui, qu'est-ce qui lui a pris aussi, tout à fait.

Comment: Mais c’est carrément ça !

Comment: Perhaps in English, "**Now**, what's got into her? Choosing ..."

Comment: For me the difference is like adding "why **on Earth** did she ...". When you're really surprised and invested, it's almost impossible not to say "*mais*". Same for "*Mais qu'est-ce que j'ai fait ?*" or "*Mais où t'étais passé ?*". And if you play online games, you'll hear that before almost every interjection... If someone dies and yells "*Oh for god's sake !*" or a French would say something like "*Mais t'es sérieux ?*" or "*Mais nan*"

Answer (score 0):

This should not be too surprising, since the English word "but" can be used in a similar way:

> You use but to introduce a reply to someone when you want to indicate surprise, disbelief, refusal, or protest. [feelings] ⇒ 'I don't think I should stay in this house.'—'But why?' ⇒ 'Somebody wants you on the telephone'—'But no one knows I'm here!'
>
> [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/but)

Comment: Hi. Actually, that's not quite it. In this post, I'm talking specifically about the cases where "mais" is used at the start of a conversation, not just at the beginning of a sentence. In each of your two examples, on the other hand, "but" is used in a reply sentence.

Comment: I get your point, but isn't it a moot question? In the sentence *Mais qu'est-ce qui lui a pris de choisir une tenue aussi quelconque ?*  , it is obvious that you are referring to something that has just been mentioned, (especially since you are using a pronoun!). How far or close, is a merely a question of nuance? If you really started a conversation in that way, it is likely that you would be answering an unexpressed comment, such as: *T'as-vu ce gars-là?*.